# Changing my .click type with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm changing my dom from:

```
<div class="empty item1 ui-state-default" id="add1"></div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="item1 ui-state" id="add1">
<img src="uploads/anonymous-1367982603.png" width="45" height="60" class="expand">
</div>
```

I have this code that works with .live() but it ignores this and does the .ui-state-default even though that code has been removed from the the DOM.

```
$('.expand').live('click', function(e){
var blowup = $(this);
$(blowup).css({"height":"100%","hidden":"overflow","position":"absolute","width":"100%","top":"0px","left":"0px","z-index":"100"});
$(blowup).removeClass("expand");
$(blowup).addClass("zoomy");
});
```

But the problem is this is still opening on click, which fires on ready.

```
$('.ui-state-default').bind('click', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use .bind() to register event handlers, the selector is tested when the event registration code is executed, ie the event handler is added to the element. The changes done to the element after that will not affect the execution of the handler as long as it is not unregistered.

In your case a possible solution is to use event delegation model where the selector will be tested just before the handler is called.

Change

```
$('.ui-state-default').bind('click', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
});
```

**Update:**
A workaround solution using bind

```
$('.ui-state-default').bind('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-default')){
        $(".upload").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but on a touch screen it may have a different event than click I'm guessing.

Comment: I was using .bind because it understood bind.

Comment: @Blynn Probably you should mention it in the question, it does not mention anything about mobile